# underscore js - renumber template rendered element attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, underscore.js

I've got an form with the ability to have an infinite number of user-added inputs.

As an example, imagine a job application with an "add references" section. There's a "+" button, as well as an "Remove" next to any already added reference.

Here's an example template

```
<script type="text/template" id="referenceTmpl">
    <div>
        <h2>Reference No. <%= index %></h2><a id="removeRef<%= index %>">Remove</a>
        Name:  <input type="text" name="references[<%= index %>].name" />
        Email: <input type="text" name="references[<%= index %>].email" />
        (...)
    </div>
</script>
```

When any "reference" is removed, I'd like to renumber the others. As the form inputs may already contain unsaved data, I need to do so without fully re-rendering the template. I'd like to do this in a salable way (one that doesn't require too much extra code per input) as the solution may be used in a more complex application.

Feel free to assume I'm using jQuery if the solution could benefit from it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this kind of thing without hacking into the code, is to use a model(list) for your so called "references".

---

You should try Backbone.js in combination with Underscore.js:
[Backbone.js documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)

There is an TODO example application that does exactly what you want:

- [Application code-breakdown](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html)
- [Example application](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html)

---

It might take some time to set up, but when you are finished, you will get work done much quicker.

Comment: I might be wrong, but wouldn't implementing this sort of thing in backbone suffer from the same issue? I thought re-rendring the template on("change") would wipe everything out the same. Or are you suggesting managing all my properties in a js object and constantly saving back to the object onkeyup (and including those props in the template).

Comment: Backbone is constantly keeping your model up-to-date with your view. When something in the backbone model (list) changes. The model view will be re-rendered. So you can then use something like index++ to re-number the list when the view gets built.